# Adding an optional external power supply to Arduino Shield

Tags: power

I'm designing an Arduino shield that uses two sets of Adafruit's NeoPixel arrays. `NeoPixelRing` (D2) can be powered from the arduino, but the optional `NeoPixel_Strip` (D1) *may* need an external 5V power supply (depending on how long of a strip is added). My current design has a barrel plug on the shield and uses a DPDT switch to select whether the arrays are powered by the Arduino or the external 5V. I want to make sure that the ring is usable even if no external supply is used, and my impression is that back-feeding 5V into the Arduino is a bad idea (for some reason). I have two questions:

1. Can I safely connect the ground of the external supply to GND2 of the Arduino? That would allow me to only have a simpler SPDT switch.
2. Is there a way to automatically do this switching with a transistor (or whatever). ie. "if J1 is 5V, then connect it to VDD of the neopixels, otherwise connect Arduino 5V to the VDD of the neopixels"?

[image]

Comment: If you have a decent 5V power supply, no switching is necessary. 5V and GND of the Arduino can connect the 5V and GND of your PS. Make sure you run thicker traces from your PS (barrel jack PS input) + and - to the Neopixel + and -. Make sure you don't either PS trace 'through' the arduino, this will burn it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backfeeding 5V to the Arduino is OK - so long as it is well enough regulated. The reference UNO schematic has a comparator that is used to shut off the USB supply when the voltage at the power jack is over 6.6V, but when the USB connection alone is used, it is just connected to the output of the 5V regulator. You could use a similar scheme to isolate the supply.

[image]

My cheap Chinese copies of the UNO, however, don't have this, and the USB output is connected direct to the regulator output - so if a higher voltage is applied, or the regulator fails, this would then be fed back to the USB ports on my PC. Not good...

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I tried putting 5V directly into the arduino and it works fine. I think I'll skip the comparator for now.

Answer (score 0):

Common ground (-) and never get two regulators in parallel !!
They play " ping-pong" and can generate interference that can mess with clock and hence your logic if filters don't catch it.
It can get ugly. Ask me how I know ....